# Use of python module like math.ceil in qweb template in ODOO 11

Tags: odoo

```
<xpath expr="//*[@id='wrap']/section[2]/div" position="replace">
    <t t-set="Math" t-value="math"/>
    <t t-foreach="range(0, Math.ceil(number_of_device_issue/2))" t-as="num">
    <t t-esc="num"/>
</t>
```

Error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ceil'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sachin/Documents/ODOO_11/sources/odoo11-1104/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 341, in _compiled_fn
    return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
  File "", line 1, in template_336_8
  File "", line 2, in body_call_content_7
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ceil'

Error to render compiling AST
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ceil'
Template: 336
Path: /templates/t/t/div/section[2]/t[2]
Node: `<t t-foreach="range(0, Math.ceil(number_of_device_issue/2))" t-as="num">
                    <t t-esc="num"/>
                </t>`

Comment: did you use <span t-esc="math.ceil(field)"/>

Comment: it gives error "Nonetype object 'math' is found"

Answer (score 1):

Odoo Reports (for html and pdf) are actually rendered views (type QWeb). The model of such views is `ir.ui.view`. You will find the render method in the `base` module. Look [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/abda3464edc40b624ee070a92ff506e708f13dc3/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py#L1049)

```py
@api.multi
def render(self, values=None, engine='ir.qweb'):
    assert isinstance(self.id, (int, long))

    qcontext = dict(
        env=self.env,
        keep_query=keep_query,
        request=request, # might be unbound if we're not in an httprequest context
        debug=request.debug if request else False,
        json=json,
        quote_plus=werkzeug.url_quote_plus,
        time=time,
        datetime=datetime,
        relativedelta=relativedelta,
        xmlid=self.key,
    )
    qcontext.update(values or {})

    return self.env[engine].render(self.id, qcontext)
```

The interesting part is the `qcontext` which makes it possible to use some python libs while rendering QWeb templates. So just inherit/extend model `ir.ui.view` and override/extend `render()`.

Edit: My example is for Odoo v10.

Comment: But ceil() is not there?

Comment: @SachinBurnawal inherit that fcntion add what function you want, is is correct.

Comment: @SachinBurnawal inherit thar function add package what every you want, you can call it in xml.

Answer (score 1):

Using External lib functions are not allowed in qweb as you have to import these libs in the context before use. So You should bring these values evaluated form controller or write down the logic here is qweb as `ceil()` does not have any complicated logic.